# changing log level of a specific event dynamically

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging

migrating to net 6.0 , i started using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.*

the code logging an event looks simple:

```
logger.Information("service {name} started", service.Name);
```

What i am looking for is a way to do this:

```
logger.Log(Events.ServiceStarted, "service {name} started", name);
```

or

```
logger.log(Events.DatabaseError, "missing this or that {thing}", entity.subentity);
```

and to be able to map the event to a severity dynamically - rather than hard coding it
with a call that contains the severity.

ideally some kind of wrapper around ILogger that would do this without affecting how and where the logs get written to (and whom i use to do it. i.e. serilog) .

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at the signature of the [Log method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)? The first argument is an enum.

Comment: Are you saying that `Events.DatabaseError` might not always be the same Log Level, such as `Critical`?

Comment: @gunr2171 , i have, but enum is the severity,  i want it out of there. A wrapper that mapps the event to severity would be good

Comment: @gunr2171 regarding the severity - yes sometimes a database error is not a serious event. That depends a lot on what the data beeing stored is

Comment: Ok. Have you made an attempt at making this mapper? Showing this attempt would help us understand your particular needs and intentions.

Comment: Found this - https://blog.bredvid.no/logging-with-enums-in-net-core-cf78e354d086. He shows such  a mapping near the end of the post